# Line integral over a curve in the II quadrant

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am lost here: $C = x^2 + y^2 = 4$ from $(0,2)$ to $(-2, 0)$.   Calculate $ \ \int_c y^2 ds \ \ $  and give reasons the sign is correct.

It's obviously the circular arc going counterclockwise from (0,2) to (-2,0), how do you figure out whether $dx$ and $dy$ are positive or negative?

My attempt is:

$$r(t) = < 0, \ 2 sin(t)>,\  \frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \pi$$
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = <0, 2 cos(t)>$$
$$ ds = \sqrt {2cos^2(t)} \ dt$$
$$\int_C \ y^2 \ ds = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \ 2 sin^2(t) \ \sqrt{2cos^2(t)} \ dt$$ I'm not sure if that's correct or where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your integration being carried over $ \ y \ $ , or over arclength?  You have two different integrals in your post...  (I presume from your parametric development that you mean the arclength integration. )

Comment: Yes, arc length integration, definitely

Comment: Then your vector function should be tracing the quarter-circle in quadrant II.  The parameter interval is fine, but you're dropping a component:  $ \ \mathbf{r}(t) \ = \ \langle 2 \cos \ t \ , \ 2 \sin \ t \rangle \ $ .  That makes the arclength element $ \ ds \ $ pretty simple...  (I have also edited the first appearance of your integral to reflect the arclength element in the integration.  Is that correct?  [It agrees with what you wrote the second time.] )

Comment: To answer the other question in your post, think about how the tangent vector points as it starts from $ \ (0,2) \ $ and follows the circular arc along to $ \ (-2, 0) \ $ .  What are the signs of $ \ dx \ \ \text{and} \ \ dy \ $ then?  As for the sign of the integral result, $ \ y^2 \ $ is non-negative for all points on the arc, and infinitesimal arclength elements are considered to beof positive "length".

Comment: Thanks, I see that then $ds$ = $2dt$ and $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} 2 sin^2 2 dt$ = $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} 4 sin^2 dt$. I am not sure where $8 sin^2 (t) cos(t)$ came from below, and why the answer is negative

Comment: The first appearance of your integral _had_ read $ \ \int_C \ y^2 \ dy \ $ , and **ellya** went with that.

Comment: So the answer should be $\pi$, right? I'm still confused about the signs of dx and dy

Comment: You're almost there.  I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found now, the arclength integration on the quarter-circle (using what is essentially angle-parametrization) in the second quadrant is

$$ \int_{\pi / 2}^{\pi} \ \ (2 \ \sin \ t)^2 \ \ \sqrt{(-2 \sin \ t)^2 \ + \ (2 \cos \ t)^2} \ \ dt \ \ = \ \ \int_{\pi / 2}^{\pi} \ \ 4 \ \sin^2  t \ \cdot \  2 \ \ dt \ \   $$

$$ = \ \ 8 \ \int_{\pi / 2}^{\pi} \ \ \frac{1}{2} ( \ 1 \ - \ \cos \ 2t \ )\ \ dt \ \  = \ \ ( \ 4 \ t \ - \ 2  \ \sin \ 2 t \ ) \ \vert_{\pi / 2}^{\pi}  $$

$$ = \ \ ( \ 4 \ \pi \ - \ 2 \ \sin \ 2 \ \pi \ ) \ - \ ( \ 4 \ \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \ - \ 2 \ \sin \ 2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \ ) $$

$$ = \ 4 \ \pi \ - \ 0 \ - \ 2 \ \pi \ + \ 0 \ = \ 2 \ \pi  \ \ .  $$

[image]

Here is a graph of the tangent vector $ \ \mathbf{r}(t) \ $ following the circular arc.  Both $ \ dx \ $ and $ \ dy \ $ are negative in the second quadrant $ ^* $, since the $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ coordinates of points along the circle are decreasing as the vector "moves" in the specified direction.  Nonetheless, $ \ ds \ $ , the infinitesimal arclength element is always positive; since $ \ y^2 \ $ is non-negative, the result of the integration should have a positive value.

$ ^* $ The fact that $ \ dy \ $ *is* negative on this arc is the reason **ellya** obtained a negative value from integrating $ \ \int_C \ y^2  $ **dy** .

Comment: Thanks, that helps tremendously. But I believe the answer should be $2\pi$ since it's simplifies to  $- 2 sin (\pi)$ in the last term which is 0

Comment: I caught that and have made the repair. Sorry for the goof.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting one. You shouls have $r=2$ and $ dy=\frac {dy}{dt}dt = 2\cos (t)dt$ where $y^2=4\sin^2(t)$ so we get:

$\int_Cy^2dy=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}8\sin^2(t)\cos (t)dt=\frac { 8}{3}(\sin^3(t)|_{\pi/2}^{\pi})=-\frac {8}{3} $

Comment: Note that there is a correction to the question: an integration in arclength was intended.